# wordpress. show list category tree

Tags: wordpress

I want to create list category tree.

ex :

```
grandfather
--father1
----grandchildren1
----grandchildren2
--father2
----grandchildren3
----grandchildren4
```

I want to click on grandfather when it show father1 and father2
click on father1 when it appears her  grandfather and father1 and grandchildren1 and grandchildren2 and father 2

Click on father2 when it appears her grandfather and father1 and father 2 and grandchildren1 and grandchildren2

Comment: What follows after the example is not (easily) understandable. Please rephrase to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function, then add some JavaScript/CSS to control them as you want.